# Using GLX on Multiple Monitors RHEL -- OpenGL, XLib, and Multiple Monitors (with threads)

Tags: c++, opengl, glx

The problem I am facing is that I have a glx based application that will render basic primitives on a single thread just fine. I can move the XWindow between both Screens and my rendering loop keeps going. However, if any portion of my application has threads, even if it does not make any openGL calls or touch the XWindow on any other thread but the main thread the graphics I render are lost when I move the XWindow from one screen to the other.

The very first function call that I make is XInitThreads, so I know that X11 should be thread safe. As I said this works when drawing primitives on one thread, but it does not work when I add 1 or more threads. The threads are in a library that I do not have access to the source. I am just being asked to create the windowing portion of the code using X11.

What things should I be looking for to fix this?

Also note I have been guarnteed that all glcalls hapen on the thread I call them from inside the library.

---

**Update**

```
[matt6809@hogganz400 SampleApp]$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf && echo "--------" && xrandr --verbose && echo "-------" && glxinfo && echo "-------" && xdpyinfo
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 295.20  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-05.nvidia.com)  Mon Feb  6 22:13:16 PST 2012

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 295.20  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-05.nvidia.com)  Mon Feb  6 22:13:40 PST 2012

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/default/Type1"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from data in "/etc/sysconfig/keyboard"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
    Option         "XkbLayout" "us"
    Option         "XkbModel" "pc105"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL P190S"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    EndSection

    Section "Monitor"
        Identifier     "Monitor1"
        VendorName     "Unknown"
 ModelName      "DELL P190S"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL 1908FP"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro 4000"
    BusID          "PCI:15:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro 4000"
    BusID          "PCI:15:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-2: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

--------
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":0.0".
RandR extension missing
[matt6809@hogganz400 SampleApp]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a hunch, but it might be, that the OpenGL contexts are not cleanly migrated between threads. Your question doesn't make it clear, if you have full control over OpenGL and windowing operations.

The usual approach when it comes to OpenGL and multithreading is to keep all OpenGL operations confined to only one particular thread.

If you can not make sure of this, you should call

```
glXMakeContextCurrent(display, None, None, NULL); // GLX 1.3
```

or

```
glXMakeCurrent(display, None, NULL); // GLX 1.2 and earlier
```

after finishing OpenGL operations before yielding to another thread or finishing the tasklet to make sure the context is properly unbound from the current thread.

Rebind the context accordingly when needed.

Comment: The only place that I could simply do that is after a call to swapbuffers. I did that to no avail. I do have control of creation of the device and the glxMakeCurrent and glxSwapBuffers functions. And before I call into the library to draw I place calls to these around the draw. Also when the draw is called I was promised that all gl calls are made on the thread you call draw from. And my call to draw is on the main thread.

Comment: Also when the XWindow is dragged from screen to screen all the 2 X (#CPUs) + 1 threads are all sitting at pthread_cond_wait

Comment: @MatthewHoggan: What's your system setup (used GPUs, xorg.conf[.d] output of `xrandr --verbose`, `glxinfo`, `xdpyinfo`)?

Comment: I ran the command specified and posted them as an update. Let me know if I can provide anything else for you to help me.

Comment: @MatthewHoggan: Since you chained your commands with `&&` the failing xrandr prevents further executes. Use simple `;` instead. But I already saw something: You've got Xinerama enables, which doesn't get along with NVidia's TwinView which brings its own emulation of the Xinerama protocol. So as a first test, switch of Xinerama in the server layout and test again. This also means configuring only one device and now two, and use the TwinView MetaModes instead.

Comment: I will attempt to do this, however, I have a Qt application that renders it with Xinerama enabled. I know that Qt uses egl instead of glx. But this really shouldn't matter. Should it?

Comment: @MatthewHoggan: Qt uses the same OpenGL as all the other applications. Actually OpenGL-ES is not available from X11. You can create a OpenGL-ES compatible context, though. But there's one important thing about Qt: Qt keeps all graphics operations in one single thread. In fact with Qt one must not do graphics operations in another thread than the main thread. If you violate that rule, Qt throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to be the GL context.  When you move from one screen to another you should switch to a GL context that has that (new) display. Use the expose event to select the other context.  That is, create two context and use glxMakeCurrent(xdisplay,xwindow,xglcontext).  Where xdisplay is the new display and xglcontext will be the other context)